# ggrepel: Repelling text in only one direction, and returning values of repelled text

Tags: r, text, ggplot2, label

I have a dataset, where each data point has an x-value that is constrained (represents an actual instance of a quantitative variable), y-value that is arbitrary (exists simply to provide a dimension to spread out text), and a label. My datasets can be very large, and there is often text overlap, even when I try to spread the data across the y-axis as much as possible.

Hence, I am trying to use the new ggrepel. However, I am trying to keep the text labels constrained at their x-value position, while only allowing them to repel from each other in the y-direction.

As an example, the below code produces an plot for 32 data points, where the x-values show the number of cylinders in a car, and the y-values are determined randomly (have no meaning but to provide a second dimension for text plotting purposes). Without using ggrepel, there is significant overlap in the text:

```
library(ggrepel)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)
data = data.frame(x=runif(100, 1, 10),y=runif(100, 1, 10),label=paste0("label",seq(1:100)))
origPlot <- ggplot(data) +
  geom_point(aes(x, y), color = 'red') +
  geom_text(aes(x, y, label = label)) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16)
```

[image: Original plot]

I can remedy the text overlap using ggrepel, as shown below. However, this changes not only the y-values, but also the x-values. I am trying to avoid changing the x-values, as they represent an actual physical meaning (the number of cylinders):

```
repelPlot <- ggplot(data) +
  geom_point(aes(x, y), color = 'red') +
  geom_text_repel(aes(x, y, label = label)) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

As a note, the reason I cannot allow the x-value of the text to change is because I am only plotting the text (not the points). Whereas, it seems that most examples in ggrepel keep the position of the points (so that their values remain true), and only repel the x and y values of the labels. Then, the points and connected to the labels with segments (you can see that in my second plot example).

I kept the points in the two examples above for demonstration purposes. However, I am only retaining the text (and hence will be removing the points and the segments), leaving me with something like this:

```
repelPlot2 <- ggplot(data) + geom_text_repel(aes(x, y, label = label), segment.size = 0) + theme_classic(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

My question is two fold:

1) Is it possible for me to repel the text labels only in the y-direction?

2) Is it possible for me to obtain a structure containing the new (repelled) y-values of the text?

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: I'm not understanding how that would solve the problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ggrepel version 0.6.8 (Install from GitHub using devtools::github_install) now supports a "direction" argument, which enables repelling of labels only in "x" or "y" direction.

`repelPlot2 <- ggplot(data) + geom_text_repel(aes(x, y, label = label), segment.size = 0, direction = "y") + theme_classic(base_size = 16)`

Getting the y values is harder -- one approach can be to use the "repel_boxes" function from ggrepel first to get repelled values and then input those into ggplot with geom_text. For discussion and sample code of that approach, see https://github.com/slowkow/ggrepel/issues/24. Note that if using the latest version, the repel_boxes function now also has a "direction" argument, which takes in "both","x", or "y".

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it is possible to repel text labels only in one direction with `ggrepel`.

I would approach this problem differently, by instead generating the arbitrary y-axis positions manually. For example, for the data set in your example, you could do this using the code below.

I have used the `dplyr` package to group the data set by the values of `x`, and then created a new column of data `y` containing the row numbers within each group. The row numbers are then used as the values for the y-axis.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(x = mtcars$cyl, label = paste0("label", seq(1:32)))

data <- data %>% 
  group_by(x) %>% 
  mutate(y = row_number())

ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y, label = label)) + 
  geom_text(size = 2) + 
  xlim(3.5, 8.5) + 
  theme_classic(base_size = 8)

ggsave("filename.png", width = 4, height = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: I realize my question is inadvertently misleading. In my real dataset, the x values are continuous (not discrete, as I made my MWE). So, when I apply your solution, it is not solving the issue. I am editing my blunder, and if I do not hear a solution to my (more clear) question, then I will also select your current answer. Thank you.

Comment: I actually applied a similar solution, originally, to what you did. Except I grouped labels into bins with similar x values. There is still substantial overlap though in a data set with many labels, and that is when I turned to ggrepel.